# What are javascript “...array” parameters?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I just started learn Javascript, I'm confused about the function parameter `...[1,2]`, why the function parameter like this.

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
let result = compare(...[1,2]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's called the spread operator. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Although it's worth mentioning that in this particular case it's a poor use, since the function itself won't actually handle more than two arguments.

Comment: It called spread operator. But in this sample code I think we don't need to do this. since your `compare` function only need two parameters (Assume this is real code).

Answer (score 1):

It's a new Es6 functionality called the spread operator, it's great for calling functions (without apply), converting arguments or NodeList to Arrays, array manipulations, and even when using the Math functions.

https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator